# Why does ListView object return null every time?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I tried to fill a ListView with data, but the app crashes every time.

The ListView returns null all the time .

Here is my Fragment code

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);strong text       
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), images);
    if(listview == null)
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),"NULLL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poster, container, false);
}
```

And here is my Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ListView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "1"
     android:id="@+id/list">
  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to find from the Activity... Not the Fragment.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poster, container, false);

listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), images);
listview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a child view (list) before u have inflated the parents (Fragment view).What  @cricket_007 posts is a standard procedure.